# Fetch rows from Mysql and display it in html using Django

Tags: mysql, django

I am fairly new to Django. I want to know how to fetch rows from mysql and get it in views.py and send it to html where it will be displayed.

My views.py:

```
def fetchDate1(request):
    query = request.session.get('query')
    date1 = request.session.get('date1');
    db = pymysql.connect(host="localhost",  # your host
                         user="root",  # username
                         passwd="=",  # password
                         db="Golden")  # name of the database

    # Create a Cursor object to execute queries.
    cur = db.cursor()

    # Select data from table using SQL query.
    stmt = "SELECT * FROM golden_response WHERE query LIKE '%s' AND DATE(updated_at) = '%s' " % (
    query.replace("'", r"\'"), date1)
    cur.execute(stmt)
    if cur.rowcount is None:
        return None
    else:
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        row_headers = [x[0] for x in cur.description]  # this will extract row headers
        json_data = []
        for result in rows:
            json_data.append(dict(zip(row_headers, result)))
        return json.dumps(json_data)
```

I don't know where I am going wrong. Have also saved required configuration in settings.py.
However when i try to run my program :

ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'Golden.django_session' doesn't exist")

Please help!!

Comment: django is advance python framework you need not to run any sql query to fetch data from db, with its builtin functions you can fetch the data as per your need. Post your models.py

Answer (score 0):

I dare to hypothesize that you have not made the first migrations.

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Moreover, you should check the database connection parameters in settings.py like this:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'db_name',
    'USER': 'db_user',
    'PASSWORD': 'db_user_password',
    'HOST': 'db_server',
    'PORT': '3306',
}
```

}